# ERROR : : error reading source directory: directory not found on linux when copying with rclone

Tags: linux, google-drive, rclone

I am trying to copy from google drive to my remote with Rclone on Linux using

```
 $ rclone copy  name:a/b/c/myfolder/.  /home/b/c/myfolder
```

and get,

```
ERROR : : error reading source directory: directory not found
```

With the same command line I was able to copy some other folders in the same directory (c) but for some folders I get this error. When I do;

```
$ rclone lsd name:a/b/c
```

`myfolder` is listed.

I have also tried let rclone copy entire folder itself

```
$ rclone copy  name:a/b/c/myfolder  /home/b/c/myfolder
```

get the same error.

How can I fix this bug? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar problem, renaming the folder name in google drive fixed the problem for me.